# listbox control in window application

Tags: winforms, listbox

in my window application i have list box. when i select any of the item in listbox
i have to display in text box that particular item please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simple yar.

```
textBox1.Text=listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
textBox.Text = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the SelectedIndexChanged event like this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = ((ListBox) sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```